# Removing empty lines in Google Docs

Tags: javascript, html, regex, formatting, google-docs

I have some text in google docs.

• line 1• line 2• line 3

I would like to find an automated way to make this text

- line 1
- line 2
- line 3

(with no empty lines between each bullet)

I used google apps script to filter out the bullet points (a special character in this case) in my text and add a new line with:

```
function myFunction() {
      var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument(); 
      var body = doc.getBody(); 
      body.replaceText('• ', '\n');
}
```

It seems to work but when I highlight all the text and click on bulleted list, only one bullet shows up on the first line. This is probably because '\n' is different than the enter key:

• line 1 
line 2 
line 3

What I want is to replace every bullet point with the same input one would get by deleting the bullet point and placing the enter key. This would mean that when I highlight the text after and click on bulleted list, I would get a bullet on each line.

I then tried changing my function to

```
function myFunction() {
      var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument(); 
      var body = doc.getBody(); 
      body.replaceText('• ', '\r\n');
}
```

This adds a blank line between every line:

 line 1 

line 2

line 3 

Apparently, there seems to be no way to remove all blank lines either.

Comment: Are you using JavaScript here or some other language?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am using Google Apps Script, which is supposed to be javascript but I think its limited in functionality. I might need to find a way to custom code it. There is also an option to use HTML in google apps script.

Answer (score 1):

The newline character is the issue. While **\n** makes a newline, it may not be accepted as a proper separator in Google Docs for **bulleted lists**.

```
function myFunction() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument(); 
  var body = doc.getBody(); 
  body.replaceText('•\\s+', '\n');
}
```

The following regular expression may be used to match each bullet point and replace it with a line break as if you had manually clicked the Enter key.

Comment: This did not work. I still only get one bullet at the top when the text is highlighted and I select bulleted list.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up copying the google docs text into a text document (Make sure there is ANSI encoding on the .txt doc) and I used Python code to run through the file and remove the empty lines with this code:

```
with open('cmon.txt', encoding="ANSI") as reader, open('cmon.txt', 'r+', 
encoding="ANSI") as writer:
for line in reader:
    if line.strip():
        writer.write(line)
writer.truncate()
```